# How to show a toast message and delay following code from running for a few seconds?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to show a Toast message to the user in Xamarin.Android but have the following code after the toast be delayed for about 3 seconds or so before it is run.

I have tried using different timer classes to continue with the following code after a set interval, the delay works but the toast message isn't shown at all.

```
// Main method
Toast.MakeText(this, "It is correct", ToastLength.Short).Show();

var t = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
t.Enabled = true;

// event handler
private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // following code in this method
        SetLayout();
        t.Enabled = false;
        t.Dispose();
    }
```

I want to have the toast message shown and the following code inside SetLayout method to run after about 3 seconds, but right now the toast message isn't showing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delay triggering the `SetLayout` method for 3s you could try `Task.Delay`. Here is my code shows a toast first then displays an alert:

```
private async void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "It is correct", ToastLength.Short).Show();

    await Task.Delay(3000);

    Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate
    {
    });
    Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.Create();
    alertDialog.SetTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.SetMessage("messages");            
    alertDialog.Show();
}
```

See the effect below:

[image]